# SAS macro date variable to convert into yyyy-mm-dd format for SAS HiveQL

Tags: date, hive, sas, hiveql

I’m attempting to set up automated macro variable dates to run scripts in SAS HiveQL

I would normally use something like this for a standard SAS query:

```
%let start_date = %sysfunc(intnx(month, "&sysdate"d, -1, B));
```

However I need the date converted into yyyy-mm-dd format for running HiveQL queries.

Not sure how to convert SAS date into this format when setting up macro variables.

Any assistance most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For night owls, automatic macro variable `sysdate` is the date on which the SAS session started.  A long running session might want to use the function `today()` to get the current date.

Remote pass-through date literals will also need to be single quoted.

```
%let   remoteDateLiteralForPassThrough = %str(%')%sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(today()),yymmdd10.))%str(%');
%put &=remoteDateLiteralPassThrough;

%let   remoteDateTimeLiteralForPassThro = %str(%')%sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(today()),yymmdd10.))T0:0:0%str(%');
%put &=remoteDateTimeLiteralForPassThro;
```

Added: First day of last month as `'yyyy-mm-dd'`

```
%let start_date_num = %sysfunc(intnx(month, %sysfunc(today()), -1, B));
%let db_start_date = %str(%')%sysfunc(putn(&start_date_num,yymmdd10.))%str(%');
```

Comment: How would I amend to get first day of last month?

Comment: Excellent thank you. After playing around I found this also works as a one liner:

`%let start_date = %str(%')%sysfunc(intnx(month, "&sysdate"d, -1, B), yymmdd10.)%str(%');`

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the format when using `%sysfunc()`:

```
%let start_date = %sysfunc(intnx(month, "&sysdate"d, -1, B), yymmdd10.);
```

Comment: Didn't realise that format could be specified..... in that case when using Week it defaults to Sunday where I need the Monday. I'd would simply +1 to make that date but how would I do this based on the above?

Comment: That's really a separate question but did you try `week.2` ?

Comment: Apologies for being cheeky! I was placing inverted commas for week.2 which wasn't working, without it works. Thanks for before and this!